# How to get explain for a foreign table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan, explain

I have a query that is essentially

```sql
SELECT *
FROM foreign_table_a
LEFT JOIN local_table_b on foreign_table_a.id = local_table_b.id
```

I'm looking at the explain analyse in datagrip and I don't really get any information other than I spend most of my time in the foreign scan.

[image: Explain]

How do I figure out what is going on in the foreign table? Do I need to parse out the sql that is running that foreign scan and run an explain on the foreign server?

I'm also not sure why there is a nested loop being used for this join. Everything being compared has an index so you would think it would be more effecient, right?

Also, the foreign table is actually a view. Is it possible to collect statistics on that foreign view using `ANALYZE`?

Comment: Run `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` on the remote server, for that part that is handled in this database

Comment: @FrankHeikens so I take the sql (`SELECT * FROM foreign_table_a`) and run the explain on the foreign server with that? And that will give me an accurate representation of what is happening?

What happens if I have a condition at the end such as (where foreign_table_a.grade > 80). Would that be filtering the foreign view first and then joining?

Comment: Also, would running `ANALYZE foreign_view_name` help out at all in this case then?

Comment: The capabilities of the foreign data wrapper also depend on the server version that you use. See the details for your version in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean postgres_fdw.

You can see the remote query with `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE) SELECT ...`. If it is still unclear why that takes so long, take that remote query and run it with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)` directly on the remote server.